# Not able to import Jsonbject and when I do I get an error

Tags: java, json, enums

not sure what I'm doing wrong here, please. even when I import I get JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type.  error here "final JSONObject json = new JSONObject();" and object cannot be resolved here "final String jsonString = obj.toString();"

```
package maven;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

// import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
// import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
// import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
// import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
// import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

    final JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("id", "uuuu@mail.edu");
        json.put("name", "Jon doe");
        json.put("average", calculateClassAverage(students));
        json.put("studentIds", femaleIDs.toArray());
        
        final URL url = new URL ("http:weblink"); 
        final HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        final String jsonString = obj.toString();
        System.out.println("JSON Request String: ");
        System.out.println(jsonString);
```

Comment: What JSON library are you using? What do your import statements look like? Also, what IDE (if any) are you using?

Comment: VScode .. I have updated the question with my imports

Comment: Check the Java References view in VS Code and see if you added your library. If it's not there, you didn't add it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue `JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type` is probably because you haven't import the library correctly. The class `JSONObject` seems to belong to the library [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20200518). So if you use Maven or Gradle, import it as described in the link.

The issue with this line:

```
final String jsonString = obj.toString();
```

Is because the variable `obj` is not defined in your code. Maybe you mean:

```
final String jsonString = json.toString();
```